# how can I override jquery's .serialize to include unchecked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, serialization, checkbox, overriding

I have read quite a few different methods of having html checkboxes get posted to the server, but I am really looking to do it without modifying anything except for $.serialize.  I ideally, I would like checked boxes to be posted as on, and unchecked to be posted as 0, empty, or null.

I'm a little confused by jquery's inner-workings, but I've got this so far, but it sets unchecked checkboxes to 'on'...  Can anyone tell me how to continue this modification below?

```
$.fn.extend({
    serializeArray: function() {
        return this.map(function(){
            return this.elements ? jQuery.makeArray( this.elements ) : this;
        })
        .filter(function(){
            return this.name && !this.disabled &&
                ( this.checked || !this.checked || rselectTextarea.test( this.nodeName ) || rinput.test( this.type ) );
        })
        .map(function( i, elem ){
            var val = jQuery( this ).val();

            return val == null ?
                null :
                jQuery.isArray( val ) ?
                    jQuery.map( val, function( val, i ){
                        return { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" ) };
                    }) :
                    { name: elem.name, value: val.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" ) };
        }).get();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a minor change:

```
    .map(function( i, elem ){
        var val = jQuery( this ).val();
        if ((jQuery(this).checked != undefined) && (!jQuery(this).checked)) {
            val = "false";
        }
```

I haven't tested but it seems the most logical approach. Good luck

Comment: That worked almost perfectly.  I just changed jQuery(this).checked to jQuery(this).prop('checked') and it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: @user975571 or simpley use `this.checked` instead of `jQuery(this).prop('checked')`

Comment: for some reason that didn't work, but this finally did:

jQuery(this).prop('type') == 'checkbox'

Answer (score 15):

This will override the jquery.serialize() method to send both checked/unchecked values, rather than only checked values. It uses true/false, but you can change the "this.checked" to "this.checked ? 'on' : 0" if you prefer.

```
var originalSerializeArray = $.fn.serializeArray;
$.fn.extend({
    serializeArray: function () {
        var brokenSerialization = originalSerializeArray.apply(this);
        var checkboxValues = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').map(function () {
            return { 'name': this.name, 'value': this.checked };
        }).get();
        var checkboxKeys = $.map(checkboxValues, function (element) { return element.name; });
        var withoutCheckboxes = $.grep(brokenSerialization, function (element) {
            return $.inArray(element.name, checkboxKeys) == -1;
        });

        return $.merge(withoutCheckboxes, checkboxValues);
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution saved me from having to fire an ajax call on every click ... you are my hero. :bow:

Comment: Amazing solution, this should be selected as the accepted answer

Answer (score 14):

just attach the data.
In my save routine it's enough to submit unchecked as empty string and checked as "on":

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();

// include unchecked checkboxes. use filter to only include unchecked boxes.
$.each($('form input[type=checkbox]')
    .filter(function(idx){
        return $(this).prop('checked') === false
    }),
    function(idx, el){
        // attach matched element names to the formData with a chosen value.
        var emptyVal = "";
        formData += '&' + $(el).attr('name') + '=' + emptyVal;
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but your solution is adding to serialize even checked checkboxes. So my serialized array has 2 values to same checkbox, one checked and the last one unchecked.

Answer (score 12):

I think Robin Maben's solution is missing one step which is to set the boxes to have a property of 'checked'. jQuery's [user guide notes on serialise()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) state that only checked checkboxes are serialised, so we need to add a bit:

```
$('form').find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('value', '0').prop('checked', true);
```

The only down-side to this method is a brief flash of your form showing all boxes checked - looks a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you for including "the only down-side" in the answer :)

Comment: Saved the day! To new guys on Jquery, use this code BEFORE serialize.

Answer (score 3):

I like @Robin Maben's approach ( pre-processing the checkboxes before calling the native .serialize() ) but can't make it work without significant modification.

I came up with this plugin, which I have called "mySerialize" (probably needs a better name):

```
$.fn.mySerialize = function(options) {
    var settings = {
        on: 'on',
        off: 'off'
    };
    if (options) {
        settings = $.extend(settings, options);
    }
    var $container = $(this).eq(0),
        $checkboxes = $container.find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('value', this.checked ? settings.on : settings.off).attr('checked', true);
        });
    var s = ($container.serialize());
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('checked', $this.val() == settings.on ? true : false);
    });
    return s;
};
```

*Tested in Opera 11.62 and IE9*.

As you can see in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/airshow/wCwkB/3/), you can specify the way the checkboxes' ON and OFF states are serialized as an options object passed as a parameter to `mySerialize()`. By default, the ON state is serialized as 'name=on' and OFF as 'name=off'. All other form elements are serialized as per native jQuery `serialize()`.

Comment: this one won't work then second time, I am not sure where its going wrong, but once you call mySerialize() on the form and then you call mySerialize() again it won't work, it works only the first time.

Comment: I had to change your answer around slightly for jQuery 1.9 and later.  See my answer for the updates.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var x = $('#formname').serializeArray();
 var serialized = $('#formname').find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').map(function () { 
   x.push({ name: this.name, value: this.checked ? this.value : "false" }); 
 });
```

try this

Comment: These is a good solution as it doesn't change the function which may effect other parts of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Beetroot-Beetroot's answer did not work for me in jQuery 1.9 and later.  I used `.val()` and `.prop()`, and got rid of the `.eq(0)` requirement on the container, which restricted serializing to one form in the selector.  I had a rare case where I had to serialize multiple forms at the same time, so removing that requirement solved that.  Here's my modified solution:

```
$.fn.mySerialize = function(options) {
    // default values to send when checkbox is on or off
    var settings = {
        on: 'on',
        off: 'off'
    };

    // override settings if given
    if (options) {
        settings = $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    // set all checkboxes to checked with the on/off setting value
    // so they get picked up by serialize()
    var $container = $(this),
        $checkboxes = $container.find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            $(this).val(this.checked ? settings.on : settings.off).prop('checked', true);
        });

    var serialized = ($container.serialize());

    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('checked', $this.val() == settings.on);
    });

    return serialized;
};
```

You can see the corresponding [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCwkB/52/).

Comment: If `$container.find("input[type='checkbox']")` not working, please consider to use `$container.filter("input[type='checkbox']")`, which filter works in all browsers, including IE9+

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, finding the unchecked checkboxes, checking them before calling serializeArray, then unchecking them so the form would be in the same state as the user left it:

```
var unchecked = chartCfgForm.find(':checkbox:not(:checked)');
unchecked.each(function() {$(this).prop('checked', true)});
var formValues = chartCfgForm.serializeArray();
unchecked.each(function() {$(this).prop('checked', false)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented a simple override of `$.serializeArray` which fixes the default serialization behaviour for checkboxes, and default behaviour is retained for all other types.

In the code below, missed checkboxes are injected into the original serialized array. Checkbox state is returned as `"true"` (instead of `"on"`) or `"false"` depending on if it is `checked` or not.

```
(function ($) {
    var _base_serializeArray = $.fn.serializeArray;
    $.fn.serializeArray = function () {
        var a = _base_serializeArray.apply(this);
        $.each(this, function (i, e) {
            if (e.type == "checkbox") {
                e.checked 
                ? a[i].value = "true" 
                : a.splice(i, 0, { name: e.name, value: "false" })
            }
        });
        return a;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You could customize this to return `"on"/"off"` or `true/false`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you do not have a large forms.

```
$.fn.serializeForm = function () {
    var form = $(this).clone()
    form.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('value', 'off').prop('checked', true);
    return form.serialize();
};
```

I also like to use better values:

```
$.fn.serializeForm = function () {
    var form = $(this).clone()
    form.find('input:checkbox:checked').attr('value', 'Yes');
    form.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('value', 'No').prop('checked', true);
    return form.serialize();
};
```

Then

```
$('#yourForm').serializeForm();
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you call `serialize()`, you need to explicitly set the value to `false` if a checkbox is unchecked

```
$(form).find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('value', false);
```

I have tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/WNCkm/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: the attribute is set all right, but serialize still doesn't show it. Your test page has a number of checkboxes, but no way (that I can see) to test the serialize function to see if it actually works.

Comment: @ibrewster: You can wrap them in a form and submit (or $.post) it and check the network tools to see what gets serialized.

Comment: unchecked checkboxes do not get submitted to the server, regardless of value (hence this question). all checkboxes have a value, since they default to "true" whether or not you set one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked