# storing checkbox on multi step form with php session

Tags: php, forms

i have a form in three steps, from step 1 to step two there is a checkbox, i would like to keep the checkbox value in a session and also to show if it's checked or unchecked even if the user goes to step 3 of the form then comes back to step two,
right now on form submit i have all the $_POST vars in $_SESSION vars but i cant make it work with checkboxes, this is what i got right now:

```
   <input type="checkbox" value="<?php  echo isset($_POST['afficher_ddn'])? "1":"0";  ?>"
   style="margin-left: 20px;" name="afficher_ddn" id="afficher_ddn" 
<?php echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=="1" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
```

but this doesnt work.

Comment: what doesn't work? you get an error?

Comment: How about `if ($_SESSION['ddn'] == "1") { echo "checked"; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example separetly

**Make a page test.php as:**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <form methos='post' method='post' action='test1.php'>
       <input type="checkbox" value="1"
       style="margin-left: 20px;" name="afficher_ddn" id="ddn"
    <?php echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=="1" ? "checked" : ""; ?> /><br>
Name:<input type='text' name='f1' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['f1'] ?>' ><br>
Select:<select name='s1'>
<option value="" <?php echo $_SESSION['s1']=="" ? "selected" : ""; ?>></option>
<option value="1" <?php echo $_SESSION['s1']=="1" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo $_SESSION['s1']=="1" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>2</option>
</select><br>
Test:
<textarea name='tex1'><?php echo $_SESSION['tex1']; ?></textarea>

    <input type='submit'  value='submit'>
    </form>
```

**Make a second page test1.php as:**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_POST);
    echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=$_POST['afficher_ddn'];
echo $_SESSION['f1']=$_POST['f1'];
echo $_SESSION['s1']=$_POST['s1'];
echo $_SESSION['tex1']=$_POST['tex1'];
    ?>
    <form methos='post' action='third.php'>

    <a href='test.php'>Step1</a>
    </form>
```

**and Check**

Comment: ok so here the logic works so it must be something in my file , the strange thing is that it only involves checkboxes.

Comment: hi again!, with your help i made it work! the code is ugly and could be optimized i think, so putting this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="afficher_ddn" value="<?php  echo isset($_POST['afficher_ddn'])? "1":"1";  ?>" style="margin-left: 20px;"  id="afficher_ddn"
<?php echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=="1" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
</td></tr>   <?php  $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=$_POST['afficher_ddn']; ?>`

the logic works perfectly, if i check i get a `[afficher_ddn] => 1`, if i dont check i get a `[afficher_ddn] =>`
and previous state of checkbox is remembered.

Comment: this is better

`<input type="checkbox" name="afficher_ddn" value="1" style="margin-left: 20px;" id="afficher_ddn" <?php echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=="1" ? "checked" : ""; $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=$_POST['afficher_ddn']; ?> />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" style="margin-left: 20px;" name="afficher_ddn" id="afficher_ddn" 
<?php echo isset($_SESSION['afficher_ddn']) && $_SESSION['afficher_ddn'] == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
```

For one, you don't change the value of the checkbox. If it is not checked it won't pass to the post vars. See here: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Now, the current standard for checked is `checked="checked"` I have no idea where or why this standard became one at the firm I work for, but it's what we do so I relay that here.

If the code provided here does not work for you, I would var_dump($_SESSION) to make sure it's set as well as check the actual HTML in something like firebug (firefox) or developer tools in chrome. Sometimes goofiness happens and checked="checked" is actually set in the html but doesn't display in browser. In those times I usually yank out some hair and clear caches. then it usually clears up.

Comment: thank you but it does not work , if i check the checkbox go forward on the steps of the form then go back to where the checkbox is then the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: how are you going back? Are you clicking a web-ui element, or the browser's actual back button?

Comment: with a <a> all the other inputs work:they keep their values in the session but not the checkbox

Comment: with your code, the checkbox gets always checked even if i dont check it(this when going back and forward in the form,  well i deleted the cache but i dont know how to use FB for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.Possibly there is some problem in passing the the value in session as i am checking the code manually it is working perfectly:
use print_r($_SESSION) for testing and post the output;If possible provide all the forms:

```
Try Below Code:

   <input type="checkbox" value="1"
   style="margin-left: 20px;" name="afficher_ddn" id="ddn" 
<?php echo $_SESSION['afficher_ddn']=="1" ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
```

Comment: this is the var dump so the checkbox is there but still not working

`Array ( [nom] => sdfs [prenom] => sdf [adresse] => sdf [code_postal] => sdf [ville] => sdf [JJ] => 20 [MM] => 06 [AAAA] => 1970 [tel] => sdfdsf [linkedin] => [viadeo] => [site_web] => [submit_step_1] => suivant → [civilite] => Mme [name] => [tmp_name] => [step] => Array ( [2] => 2 ) [afficher_ddn] => 1 ) `

Comment: is that $_SESSION or $_POST? I don't see ddn in there. There's afficher_ddn but that's not the same thing.

Comment: oop sorry the field is afficher_ddn

Comment: just to be clear, the html input is also named afficher_ddn and you just shortened it to ddn for this example, right?

Comment: right, now everything is back to normal but it still not working.

Comment: again post the var dump variable

Comment: here

`Array ( [nom] => sdfs [prenom] => sdf [adresse] => sdf [code_postal] => sdf [ville] => sdf [JJ] => 20 [MM] => 06 [AAAA] => 1970 [tel] => sdfdsf [linkedin] => [viadeo] => [site_web] => [submit_step_1] => suivant → [civilite] => Mme [name] => [tmp_name] => [step] => Array ( [2] => 2 ) [afficher_ddn] => 1 ) `

Comment: ok i deleted the PHPsessID and tried your code, strange thing is check or unchecked the var dump of the checkbox is always this:

`[afficher_ddn] => 0`

Comment: now it's always [afficher_ddn] => 1 and the checkbox is always checked, i really dont get it, thanks for your help anyway.