# How to save a boolean value from a checkbox using mongoose and express?

Tags: express, mongoose

I can't figure an easy way to save a boolean value with express and mongoose. I have this schema:

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
  active: {type: Boolean }
});

var Client = mongoose.mode('Client', ClientSchema);
```

This is my controllers

```
exports.new = function(req, res) {
  var client = new Client();
  res.render('clients/new', { item: client } );  
};

exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var client = new Client(req.body);

  client.save(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.render('clients/new', { item: client });
    }
    ....
  });
};
```

And this is my view

```
form(method='post', action='/clients', enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  input(type='text', name='name', value=item.name)
  input(type='checkbox', name='active', value=item.active)
```

Mongoose has the ability to map the params on req.body. On the line var client = new Client(req.body), client has the property name created from req.body with the correct value passed from the form, but the property active doesn't reflect the checkbox state.

I know that I can solve this problem adding this line after var client = new Client(req.body), but I must do it for every checkbox I add to my forms:

```
client.active = req.body.active == undefined ? false : true;
```

**Question edited**

I don't need to do that trick on ruby on rails. How can I use checkboxes without adding the previous line for every checkbox? This is the only way to save values from checkboxes or is there any alternative?

**Edit**

I have another case where the schema is defined this way

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
  active: {type: Boolean, default: true }
});
```

Note that active is true by default, so if I uncheck the checkbox, active it will be true, not false.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - you just don't want to have the line starting `client.active...` ?

Comment: On ruby on rails I don't need to do that trick. I want to know what is the best practice on express.js and mongoose using checkboxes. I edited my question.

Comment: Compared to ruby on rails, express.js is an extremely minimal framework. There will be lots of things that RoR does that express won't do for you.  You might have more luck searching for a library that will add that functionality for you (try https://npmjs.org/).  Or it might be worth looking at a fully featured MVC style web app framework (perhaps based on express).  One such option is compound.js (http://compoundjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on rails will output a hidden field alongside a checkbox field:

```
<input name="model_name[field_name]" type="hidden" value="false">
<input id="model_name_field_name" name="model_name[field_name]" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

This is to get around the fact that checkboxes that are not checked do not sent post data. See [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked) for more about that.

The trick here, by RoR, is the hidden field and the checkbox have the same  value for the `name` attribute. If the checkbox is checked, the value of the checkbox field will be sent as post data, else the value of the hidden field will be sent.

This was certainly the case in RoR version 3.x

More information about this 'gotcha' can be found here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

You will either need to implement this sort of thing in your node application or check for `undefined` as you have been.

Answer (score 1):

Set your Schema boolean "active" default to false.

When saving a new client document...

```
var data_in = req.body;
if( data_in.active ){
  data_in.active = true;
}
client = new Client( data_in );
```

Then save as you normally would