# $_POST variables missing when adding HTML checkbox array

Tags: php, post

When a process changed required me to change a radio button field, to a checkbox to allow multiple selections, I made the following change to my html:

```
    <input type='checkbox' name='ptype[]' value='1'> Jail/not sentenced</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ptype[]' value='2'> Jail/Sentenced</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ptype[]' value='3'> State/DOC</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ptype[]' value='4'> ICE/US Marshall</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ptype[]' value='5'> 7x/wardens Agree</br>
```

When making `ptype` an array to handle multiple selections, I am finding my `$_POST` variable missing a key. If I try to revert `ptype` to a radio button and handle only one value, I don't get any error/warning.

I've checked Firebug, and when `ptype[]` is set, one of my `$_POST` variables is not relayed. I know the max post variable is not an issue, as I only have 52 post variables on my form.

I don't know if it's relevant, but this field is never coming through:

```
    <input type='radio' name='wc' value='1'> Yes
    <input type='radio' name='wc' value='0'> No

   Notice: Undefined index: wc in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\internal_tools\include\consults\consult_utilities.php on line 53
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested, my form.

EDIT 2: Firebug POST [variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heqor.png)

EDIT 3: Added line 53:

```
$data['workers_comp']           = $_POST['wc'];
```

Comment: can we see your PHP code?

Comment: @Fred, no - second is a single radio, while first are multiple checkboxes

Comment: Added form. Why flag for close?

Comment: Ok.. undefined. Check if you have this in your handler => `$wc=$_POST['wc'];` if that's not it, then show your full code.

Comment: And the code on line 53 is? Need to see the PHP code

Comment: BTW: It's `<br>` or `<br />`, but not `</br>`

Comment: I see you're running the javascript function `validateFrm(this)` before posting the form. Maybe you have an error there that breaks if the name contains `[]`?

Comment: The problem you're describing is explained here: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Comment: @etm124 We need to see your full PHP handler code, not your form. We know what's in it. You're passing a double variable and could be getting lost somewhere. It's obviously an array and trying to pull stuff from somewhere. This is too vague for me, you guys take over. This is a `localized` issue.

Comment: @Fred it has nothing to do with the data handler. The form is not passing the key to the POST variable.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit you are correct with the `validateFrm` function. It was causing an issue. This question is too localized and will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you didn't select an option for the `wc` radiobutton and therefore the variable is not submitted.

You should change your PHP code to:

```
$wc = isset($_POST["wc"]) ? $_POST["ws"] : "0";
```

Or, as I already suggested in comment, you have a problem in the javascript method `validateFrm` which you call upon submitting the form.