# How to know whether a checkbox was selected in python - django?

Tags: python, django, checkbox

if I have the following html:

```
<form method ='GET' action='/search'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box1' id='box1'> Option 1
<input type='checkbox' name='box2' id='box2'> Option 2
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

How could I know whether one of the checkbox was selected (TRUE/FALSE) in python/django? I am writing an app in Django and I would like to show a specific result depending on which checkboxes were selected.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If it exists in `request.GET`, it was checked, if it is not, it was not checked.

see this question: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Edit: example check:

```
if 'box1' in request.GET:
    # checked!
    ...
else
    # not checked (or the form was never submitted.)!
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I use it, it does not remember that I checked it. Could it be possible that I have to change from method="get" to method = "post"?

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem. Could I see your views file?

Comment: `def checkbox(request):
      filter = ""
      flavour =["dark", "white", "nougat"]
      for f in flavour:
          if f in request.GET:
               filter += f 
      return HttpResponse(render_to_string('page.html',{'filter':filter}))`

Comment: `<form action ='/checkbox' method='GET'>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dark" value="dark">
      <input type="checkbox" id="white" value="white">
      <input type="checkbox" id="nougat" value="nougat">
    </form>`

Comment: I am very sorry for the format, but I am not allowed to post an answer in my own question after 8 hours

Comment: I see you error. You need a `name="dark"`, etc. on your inputs. I think you did `value=` instead of `name=`.

Comment: ouuu that's true! sorry about that!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of ways to accomplish this.

```
if not request.GET.get('checkboxName', None) == None:
  # Checkbox was selected
  selectedFunction()
else:
  notSelectedFunction()

# Another Way
if 'checkbox' in request.GET:
  # Checkbox was selected
  function()
else:
  notSelectedFunction()
```

Now if you are trying to get data from a posted form just change it from GET.get to POST.get - I would advise if you are trying to 'remember' what was selected to store it in a session or in a cookie. Sessions will be a lot easier to setup and will work just the same as cookies. However, if this is for a 'remember me' a cookie would be the best choice to remember the data.

Comment: When I try that, it gives me an error 'Request' object has no attribute 'GET'