# Laravel 4, how to test if a Checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to see if a checkbox is checked or not in my controller.  I've read that this is the code to do it

```
if (Input::get('attending_lan', true))
```

But that returns true even if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: `Input::get('attending_lan', false)` would work, or `Input::get('attending_lan', '0')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have this form code in your view:

```
// view.blade.php
{{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('attending_lan', 'yes') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

You can get the value of the checkbox like this:

```
if (Input::get('attending_lan') === 'yes') {
    // checked
} else {
    // unchecked
}
```

The key here is that you have to set a value when creating the checkbox in your view (in the example, value would be `yes`), and then check for that value in your controller.

Comment: It should also be noted that if attending_lan is unchecked, you will not get an error. This differs from standard PHP where if you query an unchecked attending_lan you get variable not found.

Answer (score 27):

Use `Input::has('attending_lan')`

Generally speaking, if the checkbox is checked, the request variable will exist. If that is not the case you have a problem somewhere else in the code.

Also relavant: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Comment: This is the best approach

Comment: This fixed my problem with Laravel `remember_me` on login.

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score -1):

```
if(filter_var(Input::get('attending_lan'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)){
```

*The FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN filter validates value as a boolean option.*

*Possible return values:*

- *Returns TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes", **and uppercase versions.***
- *Returns FALSE for "0", "false", "off" and "no", **and uppercase versions.***
- *Returns NULL otherwise.*

source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_boolean.asp

Answer (score -2):

An alternative is to check the array key to see if it exists, given that when not checked an Input::get('key') might give you problems given its an undefined index in the Input array.

```
$input = Input::all();
if(array_key_exists($input('key',$input)){
// Checked
}else{
// Not Checked
}
```

Or .. something like that. I'm a bit sloppy but I hope it can help someone.