# Multiple Checkboxes array with checked and unchecked values

Tags: php

So i have this line of code that will repeat different times in a form.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /> !checked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /> !unchecked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /> !checked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /> !unchecked
```

The !checked show that the checkbox was checked and the !unchecked shows that the checkbox was not checked.

How can i create a php array to get values of checked and unchecked checkboxes in order like this :

```
array( 0 => checked, 1 => unchecked, 2 => checked, 3 => unchecked );
```

Momentarily i can get just the checked value with $_POST["checkbox"] but i cannot get the unchecked value.

Comment: What did you tried and what error you are getting?

Comment: Alex http://stackoverflow.com/a/20782579/1607528

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to put a value to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="checkboxNchecked" /> !checked
```

You can't really distinguish your checkboxes otherwise.

Then: Your checkboxes will either return a value if they are checked or will be ignored when they are unchecked. You will not get a `NULL`, `FALSE` or other value. It will simply not be transfered via POST/GET to your php script as if it wasn't in yout HTML code. This covers the topic: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

If you know how many checkboxes are around and what they are called - no problemo señor - but if you don't, you'll need to find a way around. If you tell us what the nature of your checkboxes are, we can help you find a tailored solution.

Answer (score 0):

**This will print only checked fields, because unchecked ones are not sent to server. 
You will have to do some javascript and hidden field tricks.

Take a look here**
[Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[n1]" /> !checked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[n2]" /> !unchecked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[n3]" /> !checked
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[n4]" /> !sdsk

 foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value){
    $checkbox[$key] = 'checked';
 }
 print_r($checkbox); // your new array
```

Comment: The example does not work. It shows only the values of the checked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery and ajax. In your submit event get all values from the form and submit it by ajax. you can get unchecked value in jquery like this:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

or

```
if ($('#idOfYourCheckBox:checked').length > 0) {

     //its checked
} 
else {
//not checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Declaration of form...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="xx.php" onSubmit="set_hidden_value()">
<input name="arrayofchecks" type="hidden" value="toset" />
...
```

OnSubmit:

```
function set_hidden_value()
{
var checkstring = "";
for (var i=0; i < $('#checkbox').length; i++)
{
    if ($('#checkbox')[i].checked)
    {
     checkstring = checkstring + "1";
    }
    else
    {
     checkstring = checkstring + "0";
    }
}
$('#arrayofchecks').val(checkstring);
```

And the result is a string with values checked and unchecked (1 and 0)...

In my case, i use ajax for intercept submit and do set_hidden_value here...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server side language like PHP, there is an easier method than using hidden fields to supply default or writing javascript (both may fail if the user's device/browser doesn't support that method).

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="choice1" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="choice2" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="choice3" name="checkbox[]" />
```

This method doesn't return unchecked items, but it specifically identifies which items were checked. Otherwise, if the checkboxes all have the same value, all you get is one, two or 3 values repeated with no idea which item was checked. However, assuming choice2 was checked with the above method, it's pretty easy then to figure out that item 1 and 3 therefore were not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```js
     $("button").click(function () {
     var i=0;
     var cbox=[]; 
        $("input[name='cbox']").each(function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                cbox[i++] = $(this).val();
           }else{
                cbox[i++] = "unchecked";
           }
         });
         console.log(cbox);
          i = 0;
               
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="checked" name="cbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="checked" name="cbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="checked" name="cbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="checked" name="cbox">
<button>Click</button>
```