# get array of checked and unchecked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have checkbox input fields that are added to DOM dynamically.

I want to get all checked and unchecked values as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782485/multiple-checkboxes-array-with-checked-and-unchecked-values/20782579#20782579).

Initially I have one input checkbox field, with a plus button.

On clicking the button new checkbox fields with the same name are added dynamically.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lead_check[]">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#includes').click(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#include-fields').append('<div class="holder-includes"><a href="#" class="remove-includes"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i></a>' +
    '<select name="team[]" class="form-control team">'+
    '<input type="checkbox" name="lead_check[]"></div>');

  var items = "";
  $.post("teamFetch", function(data)
  {
    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.title+"</option>";
    });

    $(".team:last").html(items); 
  }, "json");



});
```

So lets say:

```
box1 [.] <-- initially
box2 [] <-- added dynamically later
box2 [.] <-- added "  "
```

Now let's say I check box1 and box2. Then the lead_check[] array should be like

```
[lead_check] => Array ( [0] => on [1] => off|NULL [2] => on ).
```

But instead, I am getting only checked values in `lead_check[]` array.

```
[lead_check] => Array ( [0] => on [1] => on ).
```

I tried adding hidden input fields too. But they didn't help either.

How do I achieve desired output in case of dynamically generated checkbox input fields.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your value is static, that's why you can't know what's checked. Add a dynamic value to your checkboxes

Comment: Agreed with @Alexis there is no point when you already have the checked boxes.

Comment: Can you select all the type checkboxes and loop it to find checked and unchecked right?

Comment: As it says in the Answer you linked to, ___unchecked checkboxes are not sent to server.___

Comment: @Alexis even removing value attribute gets me the same  result. 
`[0] => "on"`

Comment: You need to create hidden check-boxes for all visible checkboxes with default value 0 so that if they are not checked 0 values goes for that check-box