# Display a checked checkbox in a form to form POST submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have this wizard that needs to display the previous posted value

`index.html`

```
<form method="post" action="posted.php">
<input type="text" name="surname" value="" placeholder="Surname" />
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Firstname" />
<input type="checkbox" name="php" />
<input type="checkbox" name="jquery" />
<input type="checkbox" name="python" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in the `posted.php` i have a similar form only this time i know the value from `$_POST`

```
   <form method="post" action="finish.php">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $_POST['surname']; ?>" placeholder="Surname" />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" placeholder="Firstname" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="php" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jquery" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="python" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

I am having a hard time trying to come up with a  solution that shows what checkbox was checked.I have seen several solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424091/1411148 but i wondering if there more solution probably in html5 or jquery.

How can i show what checkbox was checked?.The probem i am having is that  `<input type="checkbox" name="jquery" checked />` `checked` checks the checkbox and no `post` data can be added to show what the user checked.

Comment: If you give them a value, the you can use php to echo the "checked" attribute on the input tag. `<?= ($_POST['jquery'] == '[VALUE'])? "checked" : ""; ?>`. The value will only pass if it checked on the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a way to go:

```
<form method="post" action="finish.php">
    <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $_POST['surname']; ?>" placeholder="Surname" />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" placeholder="Firstname" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="php" <?php if (isset($_POST['php'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jquery" <?php if (isset($_POST['jquery'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <input type="checkbox" name="python" <?php if (isset($_POST['python'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```