# PHP check if some of multiple checkboks are checked

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a list of services the user have to select in a form. Left side filter from a results page.
current page `listings.php`

```
<form method=get action=listings.php>
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 1' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 2' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 3' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 4' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 5' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 6' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
<input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='Service 7' onclick="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```

So I need once the page reloads and the form is sent, the selected checkboxes be checked to show the user he selected those services and there are still some others to select.

Comment: check if value was posted, and mark as checked - ie. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21968698/689579

Comment: @Sean you are a genius.I did solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, but I expect best coding.
    `array_services=array("a","b","c","d");`

the loop

```
foreach($array_services as $key => $service ){ 
echo "<div><input type=checkbox name=serv[] value='$key'     onclick=\"this.form.submit()\";


 if(isset($s))
         {
 foreach($s as $value){ if ($value==$key) echo 'checked="checked"'; } 
          }


echo " /> ".$service."</div>";



}
```