# CURL - uncheck a checkbox input

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a CURL request on form but I have a problem.

Here is a checkbox input code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="encodeURL" id="encodeURL"><label for="encodeURL" class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip('Encrypts the URL of the page you are viewing so that it does not contain the target site in plaintext.')" onmouseout="exit();">
```

How I can uncheck this checkbox? I tried like that:

```
$post = 'encodeURL=false';
```

But it doesn't work.

Where is a problem?

Comment: Are you saying unchecked it after the user has checked it?

Comment: No. This checkbox is default - checked. I would uncheck this checkbox ans send via post request.

Comment: I'm wondering what is checking the box in the first place. I don't see it in the HTML you provided. Also, where do you get `$post` from?

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked checkboxes are NOT sent by the browser, i.e. their fieldname is NOT sent (and the value also, because the fieldname is missing), because they are not ["successful"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). The same is true for unselected radio buttons.

Checked checkboxes are sent using the fieldname and the associated value - without a value in HTML, the value "on" is sent.

[Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)