# How to deal with unchecked checkbox array value without javascripts?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

Suppose I have a form like this, where checkboxes are repeating fields:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) { ?>
       <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="1">
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm on WordPress and using custom meta boxes for dealing with it. So I declared the form within the callback function of the metabox, and receiving the values in another save function that's hooked with `save_post` and `new_to_publish` action hooks.

So what's happening: when I click on the button, the metabox callback submitted the form, and the hooked function receives it. (Can be visible at [`add_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) WordPress Codex) Suppose my save function contains:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $chb = $_POST['ch'];
    $result = array();
    foreach ($chb as $cb) {
        $result[] = array( 'isactive' => $cb );
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
?>
```

It's showing that, checkboxes are not returning any value when unchecked. I considered all the server-side solutions mentioned here: [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1809494/1743124)

PROBLEM is, whenever the form is submitted, it's taking the checkboxes' values to an array(), so I can't check the array values like:

```
if( !isset( $_POST['ch'] ) || empty( $_POST['ch'] ) ) {
    $chb = 0;
} else {
    $chb = 1;
}
```

I also tried hidden field with `0` value, accompanied with `array_unique()`, but nothing seems work for me.

How can I deal with unchecked checkboxes in an array so that they can't be null, and my foreach can loop through all of 'em and store data accordingly, and correct?

I want to avoid JavaScripts solutions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- let it be. it's not the issue. it's submitting the form and I'm having the value. I just made the form to minimize the issue to core.

Comment: @Marty I already mentioned *I also tried hidden field with `0` value, accompanied with `array_unique()`, but nothing seems work for me.* with two fields with same name it'll occur six fields of same name, and the `array_unique()` takes a 1-1-1 combination and make an output of 1-0-1. :(

Comment: @Fred-ii- please don't take it otherwise. I's having the value even with the missing `type`. I checked with or without.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Yep, my bad :) You could use that solution if you output the array indexes in the name e.g. `name="ch[0]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the checkboxes with an index in them, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_<?php echo $i ?>" value="1">
```

Then you could loop through them like so:

```
<?php
   $chkBoxes = array();
   foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
      if (strpos("chk_",$k) === 0) {
          $cbIndex = str_replace('chk_', '', $k);
          $chkBoxes[$cbIndex] = $v;
      }
   }
```

Then to test if a checkbox was checked and sent to the server, you could use:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($chkBoxes[$cbIndex]))
```

Remember - the value of the checkbox is only sent if it was checked: [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Comment: We actually solved the issue like this, but I's not satisfied with it. That's why I asked the question. Anyways, it seems it's the only solution. :\

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field in the form with the number of checkboxes, and use the index `$i` for the array `ch[]`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<?= $num = 3 ?>">
    <?php for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) { ?>
       <input type="checkbox" name="ch[<?= $i ?>]" value="1">
    <?php } ?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Then:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $chb = $_POST['ch'];
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $result = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {
        $result[$i]['isactive'] = isset($chb[$i]) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all i copied ideas from many people inside this forum! i only synthesized the way!

1. my function to get data from my base located inside the **$anoigmata** class:
   `function getall() {
       $data = $this->_db->get('<table_name>', array('ID', '>=', 0));
       $results = $data->results();
       $rows = $data->count();
       return array($results, $rows);
   }`
2. code inside the create function to save all the secondary options that are not presented on the site.

   `$fields_Κ = array('history' => serialize(array( 
                       'checkboxes'  => Input::get('checkboxes')
                 )),
       );
       $data = $this->_db->insert('ΚΕΛΥΦΟΣ', $fields_Κ);
       return true;`
3. the php-html code that shows the result

`<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="checkboxes[]">checkboxes title</label><br>`

```
  `<?php 
  for ($i=0; $i<$anoigmata->getall()[1]; $i++) {
   echo "
   <input type='hidden' name='checkboxes[$i]' value='0' />
   <input type='checkbox' id='checkboxes[$i]' name='checkboxes[$i]' value='".$anoigmata->getall()[0][$i]->ΕΜΒΑΔΟΝ."' />".$anoigmata->getall()[0][$i]->ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ."<br>";}?>`

`</div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button></form>`
```

***ΕΜΒΑΔΟΝ and  ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ are the row names from my table that i'm saving!!!

i hope i helped a little..!