# How to select all options in one form via checkbox

Tags: html

I have a form with three labels. How can I select all labels by checkbox?

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><h4>Форми участі</h4></legend>
                    <label>
                        Секція
                        <input type="text" placeholder="введіть текст">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Назва доповіді
                        <input type="text" placeholder="введіть текст">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Необхідні технічні засоби
                        <input type="text" placeholder="введіть текст">
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc8WD.png. If it checked that will pick out all options.

Comment: You mean we need to send the three input values on form submit, only when the input box is checked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)

Comment: Can you add checkbox to html code?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `<div>` around your inputs. Above the checkbox. Than you can access the `<div>` with CSS, like: `#myCheckbox:checked + div`. `+` selector selects all `<div>` that are placed immediately after `#myCheckbox`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/etwnr1dr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some JavaScript:

```
function setValues(newValue) {
    var input = document.getElementById("changeMe");
    for(i = 0;i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].value = newValue;
    }
}
```

You will need a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="changeMe" name="someName" value="" onClick="setValues('Форми участі')"> Some Text!
```

I have not been able to test this, but it should work!