# Html.CheckboxFor vs Html.EditorFor vs straight HTML?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I'm using a template with custom CSS (.less) for checkboxes (making them appear as "Yes|No", "On|Off", etc.)

Using `@Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.BooleanProperty, new { @class="custom-switch" })` results in a checkbox not appearing, at all.

So I got to digging around, found many questions on here with similar issues, but none of the solutions worked for me so far.  The solution I'm currently working on is to use a custom EditorFor template.  This is rendering the checkbox correctly, however, what I'm experiencing is that if the slider is switched to "NO", it's passing across to the controller as null instead of false, and if it's switched to "YES" it's passing across to the controller as "on".

I know that Html.CheckboxFor renders a checkbox element followed by a hidden input element.  What purpose does this serve? Following are rendered HTML from the two methods as well any questions pertaining to that specific :

**Straight HTML for Checkbox**
    
    ::before ::after

When this is passed to the controller, why is the value of BoolProperty `"true,false"`?

**@Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.BoolProperty, new { @class="custom-switch" })**

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BoolProperty is required." id="BoolProperty" name="BoolProperty" type="checkbox" value="true" class="custom-switch">
<input name="BoolProperty" type="hidden" value="false">
```

What purpose does the hidden input field play?  If I remember right, only the first "BoolProperty" named value would actually be passed to the controller anyways.  I can't find anything that would suggest that one updates the other when the value changes, and through testing, I've noticed that the value does not change.

**@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BoolProperty, new { @class = "custom-switch" })**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="BoolProperty" class="custom-switch">
<label>::before ::after</label>
```

Why would this pass across the values of `"on"` or `null` to the controller? Why not `true` and `false`?

**The Boolean Editor Template**

```
@model Boolean?
var isChecked = ViewData["checked"] != null && ViewData["checked"].ToString() == "true";


<input type="checkbox" checked="@(isChecked ? "checked" : string.Empty)" name="@name"  class="@ViewData["class"].ToString()" />
<label class="lbl"></label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden field is there to force the field to be included in the form POST even when nothing is checked. Without it, the field is omitted altogether, per the standard. You wouldn't know the difference between a "false" value or a non-existent field.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

As far as why it uses "on" vs "true", that is something you can control yourself. If you want true/false instead of on/off, use that. "on" is just a default, but not required.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="BoolProperty" value="true" />
<input type="hidden"   class="checkbox" name="BoolProperty" value="false" />
```

Comment: The only possible drawback on this is that I just became the team's SME for EditorTemplates.

Comment: @Nick - Job security!

Answer (score 2):

**About the hidden field**

> I can't find anything that would suggest that one updates the other
>   when the value changes, and through testing, I've noticed that the
>   value does not change.

No, it doesn't change. The browsers, then a `checkbox` is not `checked`, don't submit anything using that name. So, the `hidden` propose is to submit the value `"false"` (with the same `name`) when the `checkbox` isn't `checked`.

When the `checkbox` is `checked` (as you said) the posted value is `"true,false"` (first the `value` of the `checkbox` and then the `value` of the `hidden`). The MVC binder deals with this string to convert it to `true` value setting it to the `BooleanProperty`.

**About the `on` value**

It is the default value for the `checkbox`. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424089/310276)