# jQuery - setting the value of single checkbox in a group checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have four checkbox like below

```
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="ca" value="0" name="ca"> CA </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="nv" value="0" name="nv"> NV </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="tx" value="0" name="tx"> TX </label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="fl" value="0" name="fl"> FL </label>
```

When user checks/unchecks each checkbox, it should change the value of the corresponding checkbox (check = 1 and uncheck = 0)

I know that I can do it by writing code separately for each checkbox.

But, I would like to know if we can write it in a single line (or in less lines) using jQuery

Comment: This makes no sense. Why wouldn't you set the value in the markup?

Comment: @charlietfl, can you explain?

Comment: Why do you need to change the value instead of just using the box's `.checked` state?

Comment: I want to change the value so that I can pass it to POST

Comment: Keep in mind that only checked boxes will be posted. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked).

Comment: This is ajax post. So I am setting the values to the post parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind a "change" listener to each checkbox. See jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/).
Then set the "changed" checkbox's value based on whether it's checked or unchecked.

Below, I've used [JavaScript's `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler) to reference the checkbox that was clicked and a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to set its value according to its "checked" status.

```js
jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="ca" value="0" name="ca">CA</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="nv" value="0" name="nv">NV</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tx" value="0" name="tx">TX</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="fl" value="0" name="fl">FL</label>
```