# How to get info from form to php of a checkbox

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I got this form:

```
<form name="formx" id="formx" action="var.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="f_check1"> Check 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="f_check2">Check 2
  <input name="f_register" value="Register" type="submit">
</form>
```

And on the var.php file I have:

```
   <?php
   if($_POST['f_register'] == "Register") {
     $check1 = $_POST['f_check1'];
     $check2 = $_POST['f_check2'];
     }

 echo $check1. "<br>" ;
 echo $check2;
?>
```

And when i fill the form and go to the var.php, i only get results if the checkbox is on, and i want it to say "true" if checked and "false" if not.

P.S: I'm using XAMPP to run the website.

Comment: could use a shorthand syntax such as a ternary on `isset()`.

Comment: Like use   `if (isset($_POST["f_check1"])) {
                     $check 1 = "true";    
                 }else{  
                     $check 1 = "false";  
                 }`     ?

Comment: that isn't shorthand but you could use that, sure.

Comment: whats shorthand then? :p

Comment: what j08691 posted. but you might have to modify it a tad.

Comment: @Berna Shorthand means this syntax: `$var = $condition ? $val_if_true : $val_if_false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this block:

```
 <?php
   if($_POST['f_register'] == "Register") {
     $check1 = isset($_POST['f_check1']);
     $check2 = isset($_POST['f_check2']);
     }

if($check1) echo '<br>check1 true';
else echo 'check1 false';
if($check2) echo '<br>check2 true';
else echo '<br>check2 false';
?>
```

Comment: No need to use ternary operators when `isset` already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$check1 = isset($_POST['f_check1']);
$check2 = isset($_POST['f_check2']);
```

Comment: Um... this won't work. It's always going to be considered as being set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This should work. Checkboxes send the value `on` if they're checked. Otherwise they don't get sent to the server at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked

Comment: That's the thing, i want then to "send" even if they are not checked :)

Comment: @Berna So that's why my answer tests that. If it is set, you get a value of `true`, otherwise you get a value of `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked checkboxes aren't sent to the server. So you can account for that with:

```
 $check1 = isset($_POST['f_check1']) ? true:false;
 $check2 = isset($_POST['f_check2']) ? true:false;
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you expecting to see something when the value is false? PHP doesn't echo anything for false.

Comment: No need to use ternary operators when `isset` already returns a boolean.

Comment: @GGG - totally true, however for a novice PHP developer this is more clear and the end result is the same.

Comment: `isset()` will return false, because the value of the checkbox evaluates to false (NULL).  You need to set a value in the HTML code for the checkbox - `  <input type="checkbox" name="f_check1" value="1"> Check 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
<form name="formx" id="formx" action="var.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="f_check1"> Check 1
<input type="hidden" name="f_check1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="f_check2">Check 2
<input type="hidden" name="f_check2" value="0" />
<input name="f_register" value="Register" type="submit">
</form>
```

Edited as requested:

The hidden field with the same name will be passed if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: This would be the most useful answer, if it had an explanation of WHY it works as expected. Please add an explanation of WHY having these fields performs a fallback when the checkbox is not set.