# Symfony form don't pass empty value

Tags: symfony

I've got a syfmony form with type checkbox or radio.
If no checkbox is selected data is not passed to post action.

For example if I have a form with two ChoiceType and i dont select anything from the second one i expect to see in post action something like

```
form[q1][]:4
form[q2][]:null
form[submit]:
```

Instead i get in post action:

```
form[q1][]:4
form[submit]:
```

I also trying to add in my form:

```
'required'  => false,
```

and

```
'empty_data'  => null,
```

but still continue having the same issue.
Anyways if i use

```
$form->handleRequest($request)
```

i've got empty values as expected but just because there isn't any request with the formName.
This is not what i need because I need to use

```
$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()), false);
```

So is there a way to pass to post also empty value?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not a Symfony issue. Instead it is a HTML standard behavior. Only checkboxes and radioboxes that ARE checked will be posted. You can simply set all the fields to FALSE and overwrite them with the $_POST values that exists.[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked). Another (bad in my opinion) solution is to add hidden fields and update them with javascript when the state of the checkbox changes

Comment: This is what empty_data is supposed to do. Am I wrong?