# Required Checkbox validation works in reverse for Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a checkbox validation before i submit the page. But it works in reverse. It's displaying error message when i check the box instead of opposite. I don't know where im doing wrong.

My ViewModel

```
[Display(Name = "Terms and Conditions")]
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Please accept Terms & Conditions")]
public bool IsTermsAccepted { get; set; }
```

My View

```
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 top-buffer">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsTermsAccepted)
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsTermsAccepted)
            <br>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsTermsAccepted)
        </div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Edit1: I followed exactly like [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2013/10/16/aspnet-mvc-required-checkbox-with-data-annotations)

Edit2: I was able to resolve this by adding a simple script (as shown in the above mentioned link)

```
<script>
// extend range validator method to treat checkboxes differently
var defaultRangeValidator = $.validator.methods.range;
$.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
    if(element.type === 'checkbox') {
        // if it's a checkbox return true if it is checked
        return element.checked;
    } else {
        // otherwise run the default validation function
        return defaultRangeValidator.call(this, value, element, param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how `CheckBoxFor` works in ASP.NET MVC - and how checkboxes work in HTML (see my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11424091/159145 )

- HTML checkboxes do not post their value in the `POST` request body if they are not checked.
- So in order to tell the difference between "checkbox-not-checked" and "checkbox-excluded" you need to include an explicit "false" value as `<input type="hidden" />` with the same `name=""` property value as the checkbox input's.
- ASP.NET MVC does this for you: `Html.CheckBoxFor()` renders both an `<input type="checkbox" value="true" />` **and** an `<input type="hidden" value="false" />`

  - If you look at the rendered HTML of your page, you'll see them both.

so when you submit a checked checkbox, your browser is actually sending **two** values: `true` and `false`. It's the `"false"` value that causes your `Range` validator to fail, even though it also sent the `true` value.

However, the `RangeValidatorAttribute` is not smart enough to handle this specific case for boolean ViewModel properties set using `CheckBoxFor`.

As far as I know, there is no built-in `DataAnnotation` attribute that handles this case - you will need to implement it yourself in your Controller Action, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Foo(FooViewModel model) {

    if( !model.IsTermsAccepted ) {

        this.ModelState.AddModelError( nameof(model.IsTermsAccepted), "you must accept the terms." );
        return this.View( model );
    }

}
```

...or you could try to implement a new validation attribute yourself, it would need to do something like this.

Note it derives from `Required` attribute, because you need to ensure both that the property has a value in the request body (i.e. that the checkbox was included in the response, with the hidden input) *and* that the `true` value is present.

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
class CheckboxIsCheckedAttribute : RequiredAttribute {

    public override bool IsValid(Object value) {

        Boolean isRequiredValid = base.IsValid( value );
        if( !isRequiredValid ) return false;

        return (value as Boolean) == true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, but note that it should not derive from `RequiredAttribute` - just from `ValidationAttribute` (since its a `bool` its required by default anyway and a validation error will already be added if there is no value in the response). In addition, if you derive from `RequiredAttribute` it also has to be registered in `global.asax` (dazbradbury answer in the dupe is the correct approach and gives client side validation as well)