# Elegant way to get boolean from checkbox using Apache FileItem

Tags: java, servlets, checkbox, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

There is the form with the checkbox input:

```
<form action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register' method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div>
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id="news_feed" name="news_feed" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${sessionScope.bean.interestedInNewsFeed}">
                I want to receive updates via email.
            </label>
        </div>
</form>
```

In my servlet I'm trying to receive the value:

```
List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                        new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(req);
                boolean interestedInNewsFeed = Boolean.parseBoolean(multiparts.stream().filter((x) -> x.getFieldName().equals("news_feed")).
                        findFirst().get().getString());
```

However, I'm getting the exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

I tried to see returned string:

1. If checkbox is checked then empty string is returned.
2. If checkbox isn't checked - exception is thrown.

How can I parse the checkbox value into boolean using FileItem class of Apache-Commons-FileUpload library without getting the exception?

I googled the question but can't find any relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked) are part of the form post. Therefore, the most straightforward solution would be

```
boolean interestedInNewsFeed = multiparts.stream().filter((x) -> x.getFieldName().equals("news_feed"))
                .findAny().isPresent();
```

Comment: Thank you! My IDE also suggest the shorter way:
`multiparts.stream().anyMatch((x) -> x.getFieldName().equals("news_feed"));`