# not getting any exceptions but data is not getting stored to database

Tags: ajax, django

error:

```
sharewith=request.GET.get["sharewith"]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

I am new to ajax,getting issue with checkbox field, i tried get_list() of to access checkboxes field but not working.what change should i make to send request form ajax and access through view for checkbox fields. 
I tried in the following way

javascript:

```
function submitContactForm() {
var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
var name = $('#inputName').val();
var sharewith = $("#sharewith").val()
if (name.trim() == '') {
    alert('Please enter your name.');
    $('#inputName').focus();
    return false;
}else{
    $.ajax({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
        type:'POST',
        url:'sharing',
        dataType:"json",
        traditional: true,
        data:'contactFrmSubmit=1&name='+name+'&sharewith'+sharewith,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
        },
        success:function(msg) {
            if (msg == 'ok') {
                $('#inputName').val('');
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">sucessfully saved</p>');
            } else {
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
            }
            $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
        }

    });
}
```

}

views.py:

```
  def test(request):
if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax() :
    if "name" in request.POST:
       name=request.POST["name"]
       sharewith=request.POST.getlist["sharewith"]
       instance=Test.objects.create(name=name)
       for user in sharewith:
          instance.add(user)
          instance.save()
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'msg': "ok"}), content_type="application/json")
 else:
        return render(request,template_name='registration/basetest.html')
```

form:

```
   <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="statusMsg"></p>
            <form role="form">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">knowledge category</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check" id="sharewith">
                    <label for="sharewith">Share with</label></br>
                 {% for sharewith in sharewithonly %}
                  <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox"  value="{{ sharewith.id }}">
                     <label>{{ sharewith.email }}</label></br>
                  {% endfor%}
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you said you weren't getting any error, but then immediately posted the error that you got.

Nevertheless, the reason for the error is that `get` and `getlist` are methods, you need to call them with parentheses:

```
sharewith = request.GET.getlist("sharewith")
```

Comment: when i rerun the server exception was raised, so i edited it. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that the checkbox value is only sent in the POST request when checked (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#checkbox)?
It looks like you are creating an instance of your model that is only saved when you have the checkbox checked.
Have a look on this too [Does <input type="checkbox" /> only post data if it's checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/does-input-type-checkbox-only-post-data-if-its-checked)