# insert checkbox value into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to enroll the student and insert the student id into Mysql database after I check and submit the checkbox value, but I already tried so many ways but still cannot...

This is the php code

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitxd'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['enrol'] as $items) {
       $insert = $link->query("INSERT INTO student_course(studentID) values ('$items')");} 
}
?>
```

This is the html code

```html
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE programmeName = '$programme' AND intake = '$intake'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$row['studentID']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['studentName']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['studentGender']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['studentContact']."</td>
                      <td>
                      <input type='checkbox' name='enrol[]' value='".$row['studentID']."'>
                      </td>                      
                      </tr>";
            }
```

Comment: Does this article help?  HTML checkboxes have some unusual quirks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/do-checkbox-inputs-only-post-data-if-theyre-checked

Comment: thank you, but it does not work too..

Comment: Remove the square brackets from the name of the checkbox element within the HTML.  Also, a checkbox is normally a 1/True if checked and a 0 (or sometimes doesn't even submit) if blank.  Are you using jQuery as well?  If so, type alert($('#enrol').prop( "checked" )); from the Browser console.

Comment: use implodeand explode to insert or retrive checkbox value in the database

Comment: @ica so finally what problem do you geting??????

Comment: There are lots of errors in your approach.  Firstly you need a form (with method POST and action of a receiving php file), secondly you need the receiving php file to use the $POST values (e.g. $_POST['studentId'] to then put a SQL query together and execute it.  You have lots of errors in your approach at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

check whether your array contains values or not:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['enrol']);
echo "</pre>";
```

if not, you should write html code properly i.e. check form tag and its action path carefully and before submitting the form, remember to check out the checkbox

Comment: Why do you think enrol contains an array?

Comment: @ChrisFNZ because while inserting checkbox value in database it contains array in variable.

Comment: check html code above, it seems within a loop <input type='checkbox' name='enrol[]' value='".$row['studentID']."'>