# Set the uncheck checkbox to 0 without using hidden textbox

Tags: php

Im trying to get all of the checked values using array i already get all of the checked box and get the value but my problem is i want to pass to array all of value of checbox, 1 for check and 0 for uncheck. sorry for the english.

this is what i want to get:

```
array[0] = 1 //check
array[1] = 0 // uncheck 
// and so on.
```

i have already tried a hidden box with same name of checkbox but it give me wrong data of array and i am sure its not the answer

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">


$checkbox1 = ($_POST['checkbox'] <> 0) ? ($_POST['checkbox']) : (empty($_POST['checkbox'])) ?'0'    : '';

output: 0
```

output of `print_r($checkbox1) : 0`

expected output : `array[0]=> 1 --> check  array[1] => 0 -> uncheck`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do checkbox inputs only post data if they're checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/do-checkbox-inputs-only-post-data-if-theyre-checked)

Comment: i already seen that bro but the answer its get is throug hidden textbox

Comment: Hi, sorry I have flagged your question as a duplicate.  I believe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/do-checkbox-inputs-only-post-data-if-theyre-checked) outlines that this behavior is part of the specification, which is why all of the answers you have found involve a hidden input.  If you use a radio button, you can achieve the desired result, almost.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a PHP backend where you want to post an array of values (using the `name="something[]"` syntax) you need to create `<input type="hidden">` and `<input type="checkbox">` pairs that will refer to the exact same array index.

You do so by explicitly defining the index in the `name` attribute.

For example

```html
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[0]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[1]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="checkbox[2]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" value="1">
```

I believe this also works for ASP.NET-MVC backends. Not sure about others though.

---

If you're looping over records or a range, this is as simple as keeping an iteration index and using it in the `name` attributes

```php
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $range; $i++): ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="checkbox[<?= $i ?>]" value="0">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[<?= $i ?>]" value="1">
<?php endfor ?>
```