# get "Export Value" out of checkbox in pdf form using 'pdf-lib'

Tags: pdf-lib.js

I need to get the properties value of ["Export Value"](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-form-field-properties.html#check_boxes) out of checkbox fields in PDF file,
I using ['pdf-lib'](https://pdf-lib.js.org/), and according to the code in the [repo](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/blob/93dd36e85aa659a3bca09867d2d8fac172501fbe/src/core/acroform/PDFAcroButton.ts#L24) I should get it by using:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
const fields = form.getFields();
const field = field[0];
const exportValue = field.acroField.getExportValues()
```

But it always return undefined...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the value of a checkBox but pdf-lib simply treats them as true of false (checked or unchecked). To go deeper into the underlying values will need a much more complex method of PDF query.

> "the export value is the value of the checkbox when it is checked. This is the same value returned by this.getField("checkbox").value"

Where "checkbox" is this. doc known field /Tagged "name"  and /V is its binary value (true/false, on/off, yes/no or ja/nein)

So here we can use one of the examples to test and even alter another field based on the checkbox status. https://jsfiddle.net/f8L4u95e/2/

```
     // Query the form's fields
      
const checkit3 = form.getCheckBox('Check Box3');
if (checkit3.isChecked()) form.getTextField('Text1').setText('check box 3 is selected');

const checkit4 = form.getCheckBox('Check Box4');
if (checkit4.isChecked()) form.getTextField('Text1').setText('check box 4 is selected');
```

With

```
      form.getCheckBox('Check Box3').uncheck();
      form.getCheckBox('Check Box4').check();
```

[image]

similar with those reversed

```
      form.getCheckBox('Check Box3').check();
      form.getCheckBox('Check Box4').uncheck();
```

for wider discussions see [Do checkbox inputs only post data if they're checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424037/do-checkbox-inputs-only-post-data-if-theyre-checked)

[image]